# Make onItemClickListener work with a disabled TextInputEditText

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` look like the following, and each entry consists of two normal `TextView`s and one toggle button.

[image]

I want to add a floating hint and a word counter for the `TextView`s on each entry. So, I changed the `TextView` to `TextInputEditText`, and they look like the following:

[image]

The problem is after I use `TextInputEditText`, the `onItemClickListener` no longer responds to clicks. I tried different settings for `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on the list entry, and also tried `android:focusable="false"` and  `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` on the `TextInputEditText`.

What settings do I need to make `TextInputEditText` completely disabled/un-editable like a regular `TextView` while keeping its nice floating hint and word counter?

Code for normal `TextView`, which works well with `onItemClickListener`

```
        <TextView
            style="@style/bodyText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/thin_boarder"
            android:text="TestName 1"/>
```

code for `TextInputEditText` which does NOT work with `onItemClickListener`

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/name">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:gravity="top|start" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Is android:enabled="false" still working nowadays?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It is deprecated.